How to avoid "Calling non-final function validate in constructor" if class design requires it?
I have some base class which is wrapper over BitSet. It has multiple descendants. In base class I want to force descendants to implement validate method for constructor which accepts Long. It will be different for each child. So I've created the following base class:
abstract class BaseClassModel {
    private val bitset: BitSet
    private val maxBytes = 64

    constructor(longValue: Long) {
        validate(longValue)
        bitset = BitSet.valueOf(longArrayOf(longValue))
    }

    constructor(vararg attributes: BaseAttribute) {
        bitset = BitSet(maxBytes)
        attributes.forEach { set(it) }
    }

    abstract fun validate(longValue: Long)
    ...
 }


interface BaseAttribute{
    val bitIndex: Int
}

But at this case I receive the warning:

Calling non-final function validate in constructor

I thoroghly read Kotlin calling non final function in constructor works and why this warning is shown but I don't know how to avoid it. Moreover I'm sure that other fields of BaseClassModel won't be used in validation method.
I see the options:

Call validate in constructor of each child. At this case I see risks that someone could forget to call validate.
Ignore this warning. It is just warning.

Is there better option?

Consider that any subclass of BaseClassModel will be ultimately responsible for the BitSet passed into BaseClassModel's ctor, so therefore it's also up to the subclass to ensure the BitSet is already in a valid state when it's passed in. (If you're concerned about a subclass being sloppy with the BitSet parameter (and that's why you want to use an abstract validation method to "force" them to tuck-their-shirts-in - then consider that a subclasss could also just write an equally sloppy validate method too - so using validate() in BaseClassModel's ctor is just redundant.

Also, out of curiosity, are you sure you even need this BaseClassModel here? The code you've posted doesn't show any public members (and inheritance is not a substitute for mixins nor linting/static-analysis (e.g. abusing abstract members to "enforce" a coding-style or convention).

The validate function is really not enforcing anything because the subclasses can just return without doing anything. Don’t ignore the warning…doing this creates more potential problems than you are supposedly solving. IMO, this should be a compiler error, not just a warning.

To include this function you must give instructions in the documentation that the function is called from the superclass constructor and therefore must not touch anything else in the subclass. Then hope that the person implementing it notices that. You might as well remove the risk and put in the documentation what the required criteria for the input are.

@Tenfour04 "IMO, this should be a compiler error, not just a warning" - why stop there? javac should rm -rf itself in this situation, because it'll force people to seek-out other languages and see how they handle program-design issues like these :D

@Dai I am sure that I need BaseClassModel  because I have several public methods to work with bitset like
    fun clear(bitAttribute: BitAttribute) =
        bitset.clear(bitAttribute.bitIndex)

I just simplified the example and left ...

@gstackoverflow Your best option would be to ignore the warning. Your subclasses must respect your design in this case.

To protect your fields you don't need a validation method because:

They are private and only the superclass has access to them.
Any subclass constructor will have to call one of the superclass constructors. If you don't do this you will get a compilation error.

In code the idea looks something like this:
abstract class BaseClassModel {
    constructor(longValue: Long) {
        // validation and initialization of fields
    }
}

class SubClassModel: BaseClassModel {
    constructor(stringValue: String):super(stringValue.toLong()) {}
}


Given your comment, I'll expand on the topic a bit. Implementing your idea would have several problems:

You would violate encapsulation, since your subclasses would have to know what is good and what is bad for your superclass. But this is a general problem for implementation inheritance (not subtyping), and you may want to consider other approaches to avoid using implementation inheritance.
Your solution would be unreliable, since subclasses could define an empty validation function: validate(longValue: Long) {}.

If you want to validate something in subclasses, then define the validation as I showed above in the superclass, and then define additional validation in subclasses, for example like this:
class SubClassModel: BaseClassModel {
    constructor(stringValue: String):super(SubClassModel.validation(stringValue)) {}
    
    companion object {
        fun validation(stringValue: String):Long {
        // validation of stringValue
        }
    }
}


validation logic should be different for each implementation
